# Debugging Cortex-M7 with data cache

Tags: debugging, cache, openocd, gdb, stm32h

I'm using `gdb`, `openocd` and `stlink` to debug an application running on STM32H7. When data cache (DCache) is enabled, debugger does not show correct values. For example if I run this:

```
int foo;
int main()
{
    foo = 1234;
    while(1);
}
```

debugger shows `foo` as `0`. Apparently it is reading the values really in RAM, instead of the values in data cache like I would expect it to.

Comment: maybe your program just hasn't triggered a cache writeback yet. So this looks OK to me.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yes, the data is waiting in cache. But not being able to "see through the cache" would make debugging pretty annoying, as you could never see the latest values of any variables.

Answer (score 1):

The Cortex-M7 processor has internal flag that identifies debugger accesses as either cacheable, or non-cacheable. Non-cacheable is the default, and it causes all requests to bypass the data cache.

Openocd tries to set the flag in [stm32h7x.cfg](https://github.com/ntfreak/openocd/blob/master/tcl/target/stm32h7x.cfg#L147), but that only works for low-level access debuggers. ST-Link is a high-level debugger (you can check with `monitor using_hla` in gdb). That means it should handle setting that flag automatically.

Turns out that the solution is simple: [upgrade ST-Link firmware](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stsw-link007.html). I'm not sure what firmware version introduces data cache support, but V2J37S0 worked for me.